# How to handle multiple new blob files for a logic app in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app in Azure that has the following structure:

[image]

Basically, when a new Blob file is created in a specific folder then I do the flow of processes but I noticed a peculiarity: If I add some files into the specific folder then only the first file will be processed and the rest of them will be ignored. I thought the Logic App would handle the files in a queue fashion method where they are processed one by one. How can I change this setting or how can I indicate to process each file and not only the first one?

Please, feel free to ask me more questions in case my description doesn't contain enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Important.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values) By default, cycles in a "For each" loop run [in parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#looping-debatching-limits). When you use variables in loops, run the loop sequentially so that variables return predictable results.

["Foreach" loop: Sequential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#sequential-foreach-loop)

1. In the loop's upper right corner, choose ellipses (...) > Settings.
2. Under Concurrency Control, turn the Concurrency Control setting to On. Move the Degree of Parallelism slider to 1, and choose Done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. Now, should I use this enabled option for both Foreach loops or only for the main one?

Comment: @abautista In those loops where you use variables or where the order of processing is important.